# Swift's Decimal precision issue

Tags: swift, precision, nsdecimalnumber

According to the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal), Swift 3/4 Decimal type is a representation in base 10 bridged to NSDecimalNumber. However I'm having precision issues that do not reproduce when using NSDecimalNumber.

```
let dec24 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 24)
let dec1 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 1)
let decResult = dec1/dec24*dec24 
// prints 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999984

let dn24 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 24)
let dn1 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 1)
let dnResult = dn1.dividing(by: dn24).multiplying(by: dn24)
// prints 1
```

Shouldn't the Decimal struct be accurate, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the issue isn't one of how the number is being displayed when you print it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber`  (and its overlay type `Decimal`) [can represent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber)

> ... any number that can be expressed as `mantissa x 10^exponent` where `mantissa` is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and `exponent` is an integer from –128 through 127.

So *decimal fractions* (with up to 38 decimal digits) can be represented
exactly, but not arbitrary numbers. In particular `1/24 = 0.416666666...`
has infinitely many decimal digits (a [repeating decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal)) and cannot be
represented  exactly as a `Decimal`.

Also there is no precision difference between `Decimal` and `NSDecimalNumber`. That becomes apparent if we print the difference
between the actual result and the "theoretical result":

```
let dec24 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 24)
let dec1 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 1)
let decResult = dec1/dec24*dec24

print(decResult - dec1)
// -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000016


let dn24 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 24)
let dn1 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 1)
let dnResult = dn1.dividing(by: dn24).multiplying(by: dn24)

print(dnResult.subtracting(dn1))
// -0.00000000000000000000000000000000000016
```

Comment: I think the question here is about why they get what appears to be `0.9999999...` with `Decimal`, but `1` with `NSDecimalNumber`. Pretty sure this is just a difference in how the numbers print.

Comment: @ItaiFerber: OP asked *"Shouldn't the Decimal struct be accurate, ...?"* and that is what I tried to answer.

Comment: Yes that was the question (and misconception). It can't accurately represent a repeating decimal

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simply an artefact of the way Playground formats numbers.

I typed this into Playground

```
import Foundation

let dn1 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 1)
let dn24 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 24)
let decResult = dn1 / dn24 * dn24
print(decResult)

let nsdn1 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 1)
let nsdn24 = NSDecimalNumber(value: 24)

let nsdecResult = nsdn1.dividing(by: nsdn24).multiplying(by: nsdn24)
print(nsdecResult)
```

Playground displays the number on the right hand side as `0.99999999999999999999999999999999999984` for the first calculation  and `1` for the second calculation. However, both print statements printed `0.99999999999999999999999999999999999984`.

Here's a picture to prove it:

[image]

Oh, and the reason why the calculation produces `0.99999999999999999999999999999999999984`instead of `1` is because (as Martin R says) 1/24 cannot be represented exactly as a `Decimal`.