# Swift: Decimal precision correct?

Tags: swift, decimal, rounding, nsdecimalnumber

I need to apply .bankers rounding mode but I'm getting some unexpected results when initiating some Decimals, I'm just wondering if this is a bug, expected behavior or what am I missing.

```
import Foundation

extension Decimal {

   func rounded(_ scale: Int, _ roundingMode: RoundingMode = .bankers) -> Decimal {
        var toRound = self
        var rounded = Decimal()
        NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &toRound, scale, roundingMode)
        return rounded
    }
}

var a: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 6.422).decimalValue//6.422
print(a.rounded(1, .bankers))//6.4

var b: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 6.4872).decimalValue//6.487200000000001024
print(b.rounded(2, .bankers))//6.49

var c: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 6.997).decimalValue//6.997
print(c.rounded(2, .bankers))//7

var d: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 6.6500).decimalValue//6.65
print(d.rounded(1, .bankers))//6.6

var e: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 7.485).decimalValue//7.485000000000002048
var e2: Decimal = Decimal(floatLiteral: 7.485)//7.485000000000002048
print(e.rounded(2, .bankers))//7.49 wrong?, it should be 7.48
print(e2.rounded(2, .bankers))//7.49 wrong?, it should be 7.48

var f: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 6.755000).decimalValue//6.755
print(f.rounded(2, .bankers))//6.76

var g: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral: 8.995).decimalValue//8.994999999999997952
var g2: Decimal = Decimal(floatLiteral: 8.995)//8.994999999999997952
print(g.rounded(2, .bankers))//8.99 wrong?, it should be 9.00
print(g2.rounded(2, .bankers))//8.99 wrong?, it should be 9.00

var h: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral:  6.6501).decimalValue//6.6501
print(h.rounded(1, .bankers))//6.7

var i: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral:  7.4852007).decimalValue//7.4852007
print(i.rounded(2, .bankers))//7.49

var j: Decimal = NSDecimalNumber(floatLiteral:  19.57).decimalValue//19.57
print(j.rounded(2, .bankers))//19.57
```

Why is 7.485 actually 7.485000000000002048?
Why is 8.995 actually 8.994999999999997952?

I'm not sure if this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328916/swifts-decimal-precision-issue) is the same because over there they are working with integerLiterals, I also went over '[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)' but I still don't know how to fix my problem, when I'm actually operating over this numbers I'm getting wrong values, like 149.99 when it should be 150.00, or 149.01 when it should be 149.00

Thank in advance for any guidance!

Comment: In `Decimal(floatLiteral: 7.485)` the floating point number `7.485` is already “imprecise.”

Comment: Thank you Dávid for pointing to the already answered question, that was exactly what I needed!